# RxAndroid 3 main thread

Tags: android, user-interface, rx-java, threadpool

I am trying to find the main thread for subscribeOn in Rx3

```
Single.just(getHeavyData())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(new Consumer<Data>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(Data d) throws Throwable {
                                        setAdapters(d);
                                    }
                                });
```

AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() - is not compatible with the brand new RX3

Gradle import:  `implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0-RC3"`

How can we find the main thread in order to do changes to the UI?

Comment: Btw, if you're using `Single.just()` your `heavyData()` will be executed immediately (when creating single object) not upon subscription (which is what you want). Use `Single.fromCallable()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() is not part of Rx Java 1,2 or 3. Its the part of RxAndroid Library. Add RxAndroid dependency to your project and you will get this method.

RxAndroid still uses RxJava2. Until there is an update from the creators of the library this problem remains.

> The new package structure has been released with 3.0.0-RC2 and there is a support library so that v2 and v3 can talk to each other without hidden or overt compilation/runtime problems from before.
>   This also means that module override tricks no longer work so you have to bridge AndroidSchedulers manually or convert from v2 sources used in Retrofit until these (and many other) libraries start supporting v3.

Please refer [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6606#issuecomment-523989096) and [this](https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose/issues/366)

Comment: Already used import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers; but the call observeOn does need io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler

Comment: Please share your dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0-RC3"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1' the sample code from the question uses Rx3

Comment: What is the error message. Also can you share your imports in this file. Did you start working on Rx3 from scratch or you are upgrading from Rx2 to Rx3 in this project

Comment: Trying to use Rx3 in a new project. The error is `error: incompatible types: io.reactivex.Scheduler cannot be converted to io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler
`

Comment: Yes I figured that out. Please check those links I mentioned in answers you will get some information regarding this

Comment: Yup, we still need the RxAndroid 3 wrapper. Thanks

Comment: A snapshot version of the RxAndroid 3 wrapper should be available as [jfrog snapshot](https://oss.jfrog.org/libs-snapshot/io/reactivex/rxjava3/rxandroid/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/). Also [I have port of it](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaAndroidInterop#rxjavaandroidinterop) that I keep up to date with the main RxJava 3 version.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with imports.
I had a similar problem before realizing that I need to reference RxJava3.
Use these imports for Schedulers and Disposable Single Observers

```
    import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
    import io.reactivex.rxjava3.observers.DisposableSingleObserver;
    import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

Also, if you have a service with a method that returns a Single use

```
    import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and the compatibility issue was from an import of the Single. Even though I was using RxJava3 library and RxAndroid3, I was still using:

```
import io.reactivex.Single
```

But was resolved when pointing the Single to:

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your import, maybe you are importing something like:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.**rxjava2**:rxandroid:x.y.z'
```

but you should be importing something like:

`implementation 'io.reactivex.**rxjava3**:rxandroid:3.0.0'` (check the last version)

that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies, you will be good to go.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.2'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    // (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases for latest 3.x.x version)
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.5'
}
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid#binaries