# RX java io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers unable to execute

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, kotlin-android-extensions

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'

val TAG:String = RXKotlinDemoClass::class.java.simpleName

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var observable = Observable.just("Goat","Dog","Cow")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({
        value -> println(TAG+"$value")
    },{
        error -> println(TAG+"$error")
    },{
        println(TAG+"onComplete")
    }

    )
```

}

Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.(AndroidSchedulers.java:33)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(AndroidSchedulers.java:44)
        at com.android.myfirstapp.RXKotlinDemoClass.onCreate(RXKotlinDemoClass.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: The answers from here could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414503/rxandroid-3-main-thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have downgraded the `build.gradle`

from

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0' 
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
```

It's working as expected.

Comment: That is too bad.  Did you learn why `AndroidSchedulers` is not included in rxJava3?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same issue using Rx 3.0. I needed to add these statements to the `android` section of the app's `build.gradle` file:

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```